# Pass unknown context to children component

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-portal

I have an external component (Leaflet Map). This component has *a lot* of children. The application draws different things on the map depending on the state, routes, etc.
Using Leaflet (or just Map) components like Paths, Markers, etc requires me to directly render them *inside* the map, so the context is available (Marker calls Map instance on the mount, etc).

However, this becomes not maintainable code, since my map is huge with a lot of conditionally rendered children (if route A then renders component X and Y).

I want to achieve a way to render children in proper places related to their domains (map is just a container I inject into). But they require context.
I was trying to figure it out with Portals, but it doesn't work since React renders children *outside* context and just projects rendered DOM inside.

So I need something like this: portal component, which is mounted inside Map all the time and *somehow* gets all the context it can access and *somehow* injects it into the projected component.

Of course, it doesn't have to be *the react portal*, but I want API to look like this:

```
<SomeDomainComponent>
  <MapPortal>
    <Marker position={[50, 20]} />
  </MapPortal>
</SomeDomainComponent>
```

and it will construct a tree like this:

```
<LeafletMap>
  <Marker position={[50, 20]} />
</LeafletMap>
```

How to achieve this?

I thought about my own context but I can't serialize React component into context value, right?

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-through](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-through) for achieving the component teleportation with an SVG abstraction.
By using a monotonically increasing numeric id on the `agent`, a `throughArea` can sort the components and make sure they are rendered in a deterministic order.

But the context isn't preserved and the context of the destination is what the component sees which isn't ideal.